How to validate user input and verify atrributes applied correctly?
I am working on a code that does checks for various things.  Everything in the code works fine, except there is two checks it is failing according to my instructer, and I am not seeing where I am going wrong.  Can someone take a look and point me in the right direction?
Tests that an ItemToPurchase can be given a name "Chocolate Chips", a price $3, and a quantity 1.
Your output
Item 1
Enter the item name:
2:Unit test
0 / 1
Tests that default constructor initializes attributes correctly.
Your output
Item 1
Enter the item name:

Here is the code I used for it, but I do not know what they mean by testing if it can be given a name, or that the constructor initalized attributes correctly.
# Type code for classes here

class ItemToPurchase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item_name = "None"
        self.item_price = 0
        self.item_quantity = 0
    def print_item_cost(self):
        print(self.item_name)
        print(self.item_quantity)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    item_name = 'Enter the item name:'
    item_price = 'Enter the item price:'
    item_quantity = 'Enter the item quantity:'


# Type main section of code here
# Item 1
print('Item 1')
item1_name = input('Enter the item name:\n')
item1_price = int(input('Enter the item price:\n'))
item1_quantity = int(input('Enter the item quantity:\n\n'))

#Item 2
print('Item 2')
item2_name = input('Enter the item name:\n')
item2_price = int(input('Enter the item price:\n'))
item2_quantity = int(input('Enter the item quantity:\n\n'))

#Combined Total
combined_total = (item1_price * item1_quantity) + (item2_price * item2_quantity)

#Outputs
print ('TOTAL COST')
print ('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(item1_name, item1_quantity, item1_price, item1_price * item1_quantity))
print ('{} {} @ ${} = ${}\n'.format(item2_name,item2_quantity , item2_price, item2_price * item2_quantity))
print ('Total: ${}'.format(combined_total))

I am unsure of what do to, been toying with this for a few days now.

Your code never calls ItemToPurchase() to create an instance of the class.

What are the variables created in if __name__ == "__main__": for? You never use them.

Your code makes no use of the class ItemToPurchase. I guess the intention was to create instances of the Class for each item# and to write the constructor __init__ to accept and name, price and quantity for that instance. You will learn more by figuring out how to do these things - start by searching around python instance attributes

Since this is an assignment from a class, you should already have gone over the basics of using classes. Go back and review the material on this.

I did modify it and got past the first part, but now I am stuck on the Tests that default constructor initializes attributes correctly part.

The __init__ method for the ItemToPurchase class does not accept any arguments.  It is supposed to accept arguments for name, price, and quantity.

I finally figured it out.  Here is my completed code.
    class ItemToPurchase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item_name = 'none'
        self.item_price = 0
        self.item_quantity = 0
    def print_item_cost(self):
        return '{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,self.item_quantity, self.item_price, (self.item_quantity * self.item_price))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    item1 = ItemToPurchase()
    print('Item 1')
    name = input('Enter the item name:\n')
    price = int(input('Enter the item price:\n'))
    quantity = int(input('Enter the item quantity:\n\n'))
    item1.item_name = name
    item1.item_price = price
    item1.item_quantity = quantity

    item2 = ItemToPurchase()
    print('Item 2')
    name = input('Enter the item name:\n')
    price = int(input('Enter the item price:\n'))
    quantity = int(input('Enter the item quantity:\n\n'))
    item2.item_name = name
    item2.item_price = price
    item2.item_quantity = quantity

    total_cost = (item1.item_price * item1.item_quantity) + (item2.item_price * item2.item_quantity)
    print('TOTAL COST')
    print(item1.print_item_cost())
    print(item2.print_item_cost())
    print()
    print ('Total: ${}'.format(total_cost))


This does not satisfy the requirement "default constructor initializes attributes correctly".

What they are looking for is your constructors correctly giving int, str, or float attributes to your inputs  Which the final code does.

The attributes do have the correct type, so I suppose it is technically correct.  But surely it would be better to ask for the inputs first, and then use those values to create the object? Is it useful to create the object with default values?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
